# When I call a cloud function on firebase from the frontend I get an error message

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've been practicing with firebase functions when I have recently run into a problem, when I try to call a function from the frontend I get an error message saying:

> T._url is not a function

**Index.js**

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
exports.sayHello = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return 'hello users';
});
```

**Page.html**

```
import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.13.0/firebase-app.js';
import { httpsCallable } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.13.0/firebase-functions.js'



    const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
    authDomain: "YOUR_AUTH_DOMAIN",
    projectId: "YOUR_PROJECT_ID",
    storageBucket: "YOUR_STORAGE_BUCKET",
    messagingSenderId: "YOUR_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID",
    appId: "YOUR_APP_ID",
    measurementId: "YOUR_MEASUREMENT_ID"
  }
cfButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const sayHello = httpsCallable('sayHello');
  sayHello().then(result => {
   console.log(result.data)
  });
});
```

I've tried rewriting it in different ways and removing certain parts of the code. I was expecting to find more about the error and what was causing it but didn't.

Comment: Your question should be clear which line of code causes the error. You can do this with enough logging or step-through debugging.

Comment: line 21: sayHello().then(result => {